# Arabic letters overlap each other on smaller screen devices

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

The data is retrieved from the database and displayed in listview. The data is arabic and the font I am using for that is "Uthmanic_hafs_ver09". It works perfectly fine for larger screen devices but for smaller screen devices like Galaxy S4 mini the letters overlap each other. I've tried different fonts, though it works okay with some of them but not with the fonts I prefer to use. Has anyone faced the same problem?

Screenshots
[image: Screenshot]

XML code

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Verse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
```

Comment: If you notice, the issue happens at every shadda symbol. try another font from this list: http://sneetsher.alwaysdata.net/a/t/alfanous_fonts_test/

Comment: Yes, it happens at every shadda. I tried the fonts from the link you provided @bigOTHER , only _me-quran_ font is working properly but this font doesn't please me.